# Powershell Assign specific License to Users Bulk

Tags: powershell

i have this script to assign specific licenses to a user by the skuid. now i would like to change to be able to do the same task, but for a list of users from a csv file. i can't seem to figure out, where to add the foreach loop. would appreciate any help/hint.
thank you.

```
$UPN = "miguel.santiago@nice.ch"
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UPN
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$License.SkuId = "3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870"
$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$LicensesToAssign.RemoveLicenses = $License.SkuId
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a block of code that executes the task for exactly 1 user then you'll want to put *the whole thing* inside your loop body, and then make sure to assign the current user's UPN to the `$UPN` variable at the start of each loop iteration:

```
# read list of user records from disk
$users = Import-Csv path\to\users.csv

# iterate over list 
foreach($user in $users) {
  # grab upn value from the CSV record instead of using a hard-coded value
  $UPN = $user.UPN

  # everything else remains the same
  $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UPN
  $License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
  $License.SkuId = "3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870"
  $LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
  $LicensesToAssign.RemoveLicenses = $License.SkuId
  Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
}
```

The above assumes that your CSV file contains a `UPN` column containing the UPN values